# Is the sysfs pwm interface using hardware pwm?

Tags: beagleboneblack, pwm

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369616/beaglebone-black-pwm-using-c) to enable PWM on my Beaglebone Black, but I wasn't sure if that method is using the PRU to do hardware PWM or if it's toggling the pin in software?  I see other references to /sys/class/pwm/ehrpwm (e.g. [here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_PWM_Driver%27s_Guide?keyMatch=AM335x%20PWM%20Driver%27s%20Guide%20it&tisearch=Search-EN)) which I'm more confident is hardware PWM, but I'm not sure how to enable that interface.

To summarize how I'm enabling PWM:

```
echo am33xx_pwm > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots
echo cape-universal > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots
config-pin P8.13 pwm
echo 6 > /sys/class/pwm/export
echo 1 > /sys/class/pwm/pwm6/run
echo 50000 > /sys/class/pwm/pwm6/period_ns
echo 50000 > /sys/class/pwm/pwm6/duty_ns
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that's using the hardware PWM modules - the `am33xx_pwm` overlay enables all the different PWM subsystems (eHRPWM, eCAP), then the PWM kernel driver configures the corresponding PWM module for the pin being configured.